# Приходит письмо с ромбиками в текстовом поле. Что сделать?

Tags: php, sendmail

При отправке письма стандартный текст .txt файла кодировка UTF-8 приходит нормально, а вот тот текст который вводиться пользователем приходит ромбиками. Что сделать?

```
﻿Здравствуйте!

Поступило новое сообщение из Form:

IP пользователя: 111.11.111.11
E-mail пользователя: dddddddd@mail.ru

Мнение пользователя: 
����
```

Как правильно эту функцию (<?php echo iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", "Пора переходить на юникод."); ?>) к этому блоку прикрутить?..

```
if ($_POST['sendMail'] == 1) { 
    $replyArray = array(
        "[user_ip]" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        "[type]" => $_POST['type'],
        "[email]" => $_POST['email'],
        "[info]" => $_POST['description'],
        "[footer]" => _EMAIL_FOOTER,
    );
    $basic->notifiEmail('templates/mails/onlineForm.txt', $replyArray, ADMIN_EMAIL, $_POST['type'] . 'Form ' . _SUBJECT_CONTACT_FORM);
}
```

глючит эта строка "[info]" => $_POST['description'],

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в кодировке возможно. (страница/сервер возможно отличается).
Попробуйте функцию iconv

Comment: Типа этого
<?php
echo iconv("KOI8-U", "UTF-8", "Пора переходить на юникод.");
?>

Comment: Да. Большинство случаев нужно  
<?php echo iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", "Пора переходить на юникод."); ?>

Comment: Как правильно его к этому блоку прикрутить...

См вверху
глючит 
эта строка
"[info]" => $_POST['description'],

Comment: @Greg8888 Вы это серьезно?

    "[info]" => iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $_POST['description']),

Comment: Спасибо всем!!!